# Save state of an android application when the back button is pressed

Tags: android

i have noticed while working in the emulator that whenever i get out of my app via any method other than pressing the back button, my toggle button (if pressed) will have its state saved and return to that state when i return to the app. im guessing its because its value gets saved in a bundle and reloaded when i return. when i leave the app via the back button, this does not happen and the toggle is always off when i return. is there any way to get the value of the toggle back if the user leaves via the back button, without having to save the value in a db table? alternatively, if my apps notification is in the status bar, i can be confident that the toggle should always be selected, so if there is no way to save the state, is there a way to find out if my apps notification is currently being displayed? then it would be easy to just set the toggle each time via a quick check of the status bar

thx in advance

Comment: If the status of that toggle is transient state and not intended to be a persistent user preference, you may be breaking Android convention if you save it when the user exits the app with the Back key.  Android Dev Guide, Application Fundamentals: "Android calls onSaveInstanceState() before the activity becomes vulnerable to being destroyed by the system, but does not bother calling it when the instance is actually being destroyed by a user action (such as pressing the BACK key). In that case, the user won't expect to return to the activity, so there's no reason to save its state."

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to cache the value and get it back.